# Getting [object Object] when outputting result

Tags: javascript

I am not sure why I am getting `[object Object]`. I want to be able to work with the data that comes out of it. If you have any ideas I would appreciate it. Thank you!

```
const response = await axios.get(url);
    const { data } = response;

    const result = data.map(item => ({
      date: Date.parse(item.date),
      open: item.open,
      high: item.high,
      low: item.low,
      close: item.close,
      volume: item.volume,
    }));

    console.log(`fetchWebApiStock result data: ${result}`);
```

**edited:**

```
console.log('fetchWebApiStock result data:', result);
```

Comment: You probably just want to stringily `item`: `console.log(\`result data: ${JSON.stringify(item)}\`)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the string is concateneted with an Object.

I prefer:

```
`console.log('result data: ', item)`
```

This helps me to also expand collapse the object and analyze it nicely on the browser console.

Comment: @JohnJohn I don't understand, do you mean you get both the Object and 'undefined' printed in the console in two separate lines?

Comment: I edited my question. I am not sure where I am getting it wrong but for some reason I am not getting the result.

Comment: @JohnJohn That would be because a for loop doesn't return anything. Maybe you can push the results inside an array in the loop then return the array outside the loop. Apart from that, you need to make the inner function an IIFE, or call it manually

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `JSON.stringify()` for the object only. Currently, your object is concatenating with the string value which will make the entire result as string and stringifying it will then show the object as string.

```js
const result = () => {
  return {
    someProperty: 12
  };
};

var res = result();
console.log('result data:' + JSON.stringify(res))
```

Even if you do not use `JSON.stringify()` the way you did, it implicitly convert the object to string as shown below. That is why your code do not work:

```js
const result = () => {
  return {
    someProperty: 12
  };
};

var res = result();
console.log(`result data: (${res})`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
console.log(`result data: ${JSON.stringify(item)}`)
```